# Setting a user to be Authenticated ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, active-directory, asp.net-identity, membership

I am having some problems with AD authentication in MVC. In my controller I have the following:

```
public static SignInStatus Login(string userid, string password) {
        // Attempt to login using the supplied credentials
        SignInStatus result = IsAuthenticated(@"LDAP://myladapserver", userid, password);

        if (result == SignInStatus.Success)
        {
           // What do I put here, so that when I call User.Identity.IsAuthenticated I get true??

        }
        return result;
    }
```

My question is, How do I actually log the user in, after getting a sucessful response from AD, so that when I call User.Identity.IsAuthenticated, I get the correct response?

BTW The IsAuthenticated() call simply authenticates the userid and password against AD.

Comment: what version of mvc are you using. There are a few different ways to do this centering around using cookies

Comment: Hi Nkosi, I'm using MVC v5, framework v 4.5. Thanks.